# yii2 аутентификация пользователя без active record, с помощью DAO

Tags: php, yii2, ооп, интерфейс

Пытаюсь переписать готовую библиотеку по аутентификации пользователя.
Хочу использовать DAO вместо ActiveRecord. И на определенном этапе застрял, никак не получается решить проблему.

У меня есть недопонимание по работе с интерфейсами и
почему с ActiveRecord все работает, а с DAO нет

Например как правильно сделать возврат с метода класса реализующем интерфейс, 
чтобы потом результат вызова этого метода можно было передать в метод, который требует аргумент типа интерфейс.

Вот абстрактный пример, что я имею ввиду

```
use Yii;
use yii\web\Controller;
use app\models\User;

class User extends ActiveRecord implements IdentityInterface
{
   public function foo($id)
   {

        return static::findOne($id); // Так все работает

       // Так не работает
       $sql = '
          SELECT * 
          FROM user 
          WHERE id=:id
      ';
      return Yii::$app->db->createCommand($sql)
      ->bindValue(':id', $id)
      ->queryOne();
   }
}

class AuthController extends Controller
{
   function attemptLogin($client)
   {
       $user = new User();
       $user = $user->foo($id);

       // Ошибка: Argument 1 passed to yii\web\User::login() must implement 
       // interface yii\web\IdentityInterface
       login($user); 
   }
}

// В ядре фреймворка (yiisoft\yii2\web\User.php)
public function login(IdentityInterface $identity, $duration = 0)
{
   ...
}
```

Аналогичная проблема и в реализации методов интерфейса

```
class User extends ActiveRecord implements IdentityInterface
{
   public static function findIdentity($id)
   {
       return static::findOne($id); // ActiveRecord, все работает

       // DAO, Так не работает
        $sql = '
          SELECT * 
          FROM user 
          WHERE id=:id
        ';
        return Yii::$app->db->createCommand($sql)
        ->bindValue(':id', $id)
        ->queryOne();
    }
}
```

В этом случае уже возникает чуть другая ошибка

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

static::findOne($id) вам возвращает модель, а Yii::$app->db->createCommand($sql)->queryOne() вернет массив или false. Насколько я знаю class реализующий IdentityInterface должен вернуть объект, а не массив. Еще у вас нет текст ошибки, чтоб что-то конкретней вам посоветовать.